# java - How to use Assert.assertEquals when sometimes a String is returned and sometimes null is returned

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

*This is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm a complete beginner so I apologize if my question is vague*

I have a method that will sometimes return a String and sometimes return null.

```
public String confirmLogo() {
String logo = null;

if(sql.getLogo(ID).equals("Qwerty Logo")
logo += "Qwerty Logo";

return logo;
}
```

So sometimes "qwerty logo" will be returned and sometimes it will return null.

Then in a test class, I'm trying to confirm that whats returned matched whats expected.

```
String primaryLogo = getLogoName(ID);
Assert.assert.equals(primaryLogo, example.confirmLogo());
```

I'm understandably getting NPEs (java.lang.NullPointerException) returned but I was wondering how I can accomplish this or if someone can't point me to an appropriate reference.

Comment: Can you post full code? and stack trace of nullpointer? What is 'x' in this line? if(x.equals("test")

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile. If you want to prevent null pointer exceptions during the equals process, which I don't believe will happen anyways since I think the null check is already programmed in, you can assertNotNull.

Comment: Use Assert.assertTrue (org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.equals(primaryLogo , example.confirmLogo()));

Answer (score 2):

Your test should be predictable I would use two different tests to test this, one that expects `null` and one that doesn't. Use different input parameters to achieve the desired behavior (e.g. once provide `x = "test"`, and in other use `x = "other"`).

Unless you really have e.g. a `Math.random()` in the method :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the JavaDoc of `Assert.assertEquals()` (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

> Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not, an AssertionError without a message is thrown. **If expected and actual are null, they are considered equal**.

you should never get a `NullPointerException` from calling `Assert.assertEquals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a reference for the Assert class [here.](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

When it is exepcted to return null, you can use assertNull.
When it isn't, you can use assertNotNull before you assertEquals -- avoiding the NPE.